# How to stop mouse click when clicking on a dialog using java swt

Tags: java, swt, jface

I have a dialog and when the user clicks the ok button in the dialog, the call goes from client to the server and then starts processing. In mean time when it is in the processing stage when the user tries to click anywhere on the dialog it is getting hanged and then once the process gets complete it behaves normally. So until the process gets complete i dont want the user to click the dialog, even though if he clicks the event should not be detected and dialog should not get hanged.

I dont want use progress monitor, is there anyway to handle this?

This is code I am using after OK button Pressed

```
`//Server call
startServerProcess(compsTable); 
//Async to update UI 
Display.getDefault().asyncExec( new Runnable() 
{ 
    public void run() 
    { 
        label.setText("");
    }
 });`
```

Even though the async call is used, when user clicks anywhere on the dialog it shows hanged and says not responding. Any help for this? –

Comment: Is this just SWT, or SWT + JFace, or an Eclipse plugin?

Comment: This is SWT + JFace. I have created my own dialog by extending org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog;

Comment: Doing this with a wizard using `WizardDialog` gives you access to a progress monitor that deals with disabling the dialog controls while your work runs.

Comment: Greg, you might be right to use the wizardDialog with progess monitor, but the user requirement is not to use the progess monitor. I need to achieve this without using progress monitor

Comment: Not using a progress monitor means you will have to spend a lot of time reproducing the things that the monitor does.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are doing it asynchronously, it will behave like it does.  the SWT is waiting until it gets the response back from the server, and during that time, whatever you do (e.g. click or do other actions) will not have any affect because it is not ready for user interaction yet.

You can run the job in a Thread, but ProgressMonitor was designed to give you a nice modal UI dialog telling you to wait.  If you run a separate thread, you'll have to check if they click on the OK button twice, or some other element you left accessible.

Comment: I tried using the async at the point where the server call starts but it says invalid thread access..give me some time i will post u the code.

Comment: Put your's server connecting code in another thread and update UI from asyncExec()

Comment: This is code I am using after OK Pressed 
`//Server call`

`startServerProcess(compsTable);

//Async to update UI
Display.getDefault().asyncExec( new Runnable()
{
          public void run()
         {
          label.setText(""); 
         }
});`

Even though the async call is used, when user clicks anywhere on the dialog it shows hanged and says not responding. Any help for this?

Comment: @ergonaut..i have updated the code in my question..can you please check and help me to resolve the issue..

Comment: @ergonaut..The issue still not solved from my end..any help on this to resolve the issue..I have updated my question with the code that I am using.

Answer (score 0):

I my opinion ergonaut's answer is correct and You should go with threads and asynchronous processing.

But if You insist to do it in one UI(!) thread then disable dialog parent composite, send, receive and process server's response. Then enable parent composite. This will block unnecessary events during processing.

```
parent.setEnable(false);
send(message)
process(recv());
parent.setEnable(true);
```

Be aware that user expects some kind of notification when something is processing. Without showing that app is busy user probably assume that application hangs and terminate it.

Comment: User will not expect any notification. After the server processing gets completes with out any error the dialog should close.

Comment: Your's app will freeze and some users will termiate it. Unless of course You know all of users.